# Can anyone explain me what is the reason behind this behaviour of npm have I not installed the dependencies correctly or is it something else

Tags: node.js, npm

`PS E:\test> npm install <packagename> --save -dev
Says --dev option is depreacated use --only=dev
npm WARN install Usage of the --dev option is deprecated. Use --only=dev instead.`

When I change my call to npm as shown below

`PS E:\test> npm install <packagename> --only=dev`
I get the following error

`-- (empty)
npm ERR! code`

How can I debug this and know more about it ??

Answer (score 7):

This is really an interesting situation. Indeed you made a typo. Instead of writing `--save-dev` you wrote `--save -dev`. There is already a `--dev` argument which can be used in order to install only the development dependencies that are defined in your package.json. Probably the parser thinks that you wanted to type `--dev` instead of `-dev` so it gives you the deprecation warning. The `--dev` is deprecated and is replaced by the `--only=dev` argument. This only works for the entire package.json and not for a specific package. So the `npm install <packagename> --only=dev` is kind of invalid.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to install **a new module** and save it `devDependencies` section in package.json you should use the command:

```
npm i <packagename> -D
# or:
npm i <packagename> --save-dev # without space
```

If your `devDependencies` section is not empty, and you want to install **only** modules from that section you should use the command:

```
npm i --only=dev
```

> The --only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]} argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the option. The correct option is [`--save-dev`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), not `--save -dev`

Answer (score -1):

You will need mention your node and npm versions as when I try this:

```
npm install bower --save-dev
```

This works fine.